Capturing Specific Warnings from a Model Fitted with brms
I'm trying to capture and store the specific warnings that occasionally appear when fitting a Bayesian model using the brms::brm() function in R. The challenge is to do this without having to fit the model twice, which is time-consuming.
For example, when fitting the following model:
mdl <- brms::brm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width*Petal.Length*Petal.Width, data = iris, seed = 123)

I receive two warning messages:
Warning messages:
1: There were 8 transitions after warmup that exceeded the maximum treedepth. Increase max_treedepth above 10. See
https://mc-stan.org/misc/warnings.html#maximum-treedepth-exceeded 
2: Examine the pairs() plot to diagnose sampling problems

I want to capture these warnings that are specific to the model fit. This is particularly important as this model is fitted within a lengthy script that may generate numerous warnings before and after the model is fitted. Ideally, I would like to create a function like get_model_warnings(mdl).
Here's my current approach:
expandFunctions::reset.warnings()
mdl <- brms::brm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width*Petal.Length*Petal.Width, data = iris, seed = 123)
mdl_warning <- names(last.warning)

This code does capture the warnings, but it's not ideal as it clears all previous warnings. Also, it does not allow to retroactively capture the warnings that were thrown when fitting the model.

Using purrr quietly which stores the warnings along with the model result:
library(purrr)
library(brms)

quiet_brm <- quietly(brm)

mdl <- quiet_brm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width * Petal.Length * Petal.Width, data = iris, seed = 123)

mdl$warnings
#> [1] "There were 9 transitions after warmup that exceeded the maximum treedepth. Increase max_treedepth above 10. See\nhttps://mc-stan.org/misc/warnings.html#maximum-treedepth-exceeded"
#> [2] "Examine the pairs() plot to diagnose sampling problems\n"

Created on 2024-04-18 with reprex v2.1.0

Use the improved tryCath.W.E posted as an answer here.
I adapt that function to return a list of all warnings, not just the last one like in the answer linked to.
tryCatch.W.E <- function(expr)
{
  W <- list()
  i <- 0L
  w.handler <- function(w){ # warning handler
    i <<- i + 1L
    W[[i]] <<- w
    invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
  }
  list(value = withCallingHandlers(tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) e),
                                   warning = w.handler),
       warnings = W)
}

mdl2 <- tryCatch.W.E(
  brms::brm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width * Petal.Length * Petal.Width, data = iris)
)
#> Compiling Stan program...
#> Start sampling
#> 
#> SAMPLING FOR MODEL 'anon_model' NOW (CHAIN 1).
#> Chain 1: 
#> Chain 1: Gradient evaluation took 4.9e-05 seconds
#> Chain 1: 1000 transitions using 10 leapfrog steps per transition would take 0.49 seconds.
#> Chain 1: Adjust your expectations accordingly!
#> Chain 1: 
#> Chain 1: 
#> Chain 1: Iteration:    1 / 2000 [  0%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 1: Iteration:  200 / 2000 [ 10%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 1: Iteration:  400 / 2000 [ 20%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 1: Iteration:  600 / 2000 [ 30%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 1: Iteration:  800 / 2000 [ 40%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 1: Iteration: 1000 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 1: Iteration: 1001 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 1: Iteration: 1200 / 2000 [ 60%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 1: Iteration: 1400 / 2000 [ 70%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 1: Iteration: 1600 / 2000 [ 80%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 1: Iteration: 1800 / 2000 [ 90%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 1: Iteration: 2000 / 2000 [100%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 1: 
#> Chain 1:  Elapsed Time: 1.511 seconds (Warm-up)
#> Chain 1:                2.097 seconds (Sampling)
#> Chain 1:                3.608 seconds (Total)
#> Chain 1: 
#> 
#> SAMPLING FOR MODEL 'anon_model' NOW (CHAIN 2).
#> Chain 2: 
#> Chain 2: Gradient evaluation took 8e-06 seconds
#> Chain 2: 1000 transitions using 10 leapfrog steps per transition would take 0.08 seconds.
#> Chain 2: Adjust your expectations accordingly!
#> Chain 2: 
#> Chain 2: 
#> Chain 2: Iteration:    1 / 2000 [  0%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 2: Iteration:  200 / 2000 [ 10%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 2: Iteration:  400 / 2000 [ 20%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 2: Iteration:  600 / 2000 [ 30%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 2: Iteration:  800 / 2000 [ 40%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 2: Iteration: 1000 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 2: Iteration: 1001 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 2: Iteration: 1200 / 2000 [ 60%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 2: Iteration: 1400 / 2000 [ 70%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 2: Iteration: 1600 / 2000 [ 80%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 2: Iteration: 1800 / 2000 [ 90%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 2: Iteration: 2000 / 2000 [100%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 2: 
#> Chain 2:  Elapsed Time: 1.359 seconds (Warm-up)
#> Chain 2:                1.606 seconds (Sampling)
#> Chain 2:                2.965 seconds (Total)
#> Chain 2: 
#> 
#> SAMPLING FOR MODEL 'anon_model' NOW (CHAIN 3).
#> Chain 3: 
#> Chain 3: Gradient evaluation took 1e-05 seconds
#> Chain 3: 1000 transitions using 10 leapfrog steps per transition would take 0.1 seconds.
#> Chain 3: Adjust your expectations accordingly!
#> Chain 3: 
#> Chain 3: 
#> Chain 3: Iteration:    1 / 2000 [  0%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 3: Iteration:  200 / 2000 [ 10%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 3: Iteration:  400 / 2000 [ 20%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 3: Iteration:  600 / 2000 [ 30%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 3: Iteration:  800 / 2000 [ 40%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 3: Iteration: 1000 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 3: Iteration: 1001 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 3: Iteration: 1200 / 2000 [ 60%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 3: Iteration: 1400 / 2000 [ 70%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 3: Iteration: 1600 / 2000 [ 80%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 3: Iteration: 1800 / 2000 [ 90%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 3: Iteration: 2000 / 2000 [100%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 3: 
#> Chain 3:  Elapsed Time: 1.344 seconds (Warm-up)
#> Chain 3:                1.94 seconds (Sampling)
#> Chain 3:                3.284 seconds (Total)
#> Chain 3: 
#> 
#> SAMPLING FOR MODEL 'anon_model' NOW (CHAIN 4).
#> Chain 4: 
#> Chain 4: Gradient evaluation took 1.2e-05 seconds
#> Chain 4: 1000 transitions using 10 leapfrog steps per transition would take 0.12 seconds.
#> Chain 4: Adjust your expectations accordingly!
#> Chain 4: 
#> Chain 4: 
#> Chain 4: Iteration:    1 / 2000 [  0%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 4: Iteration:  200 / 2000 [ 10%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 4: Iteration:  400 / 2000 [ 20%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 4: Iteration:  600 / 2000 [ 30%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 4: Iteration:  800 / 2000 [ 40%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 4: Iteration: 1000 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Warmup)
#> Chain 4: Iteration: 1001 / 2000 [ 50%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 4: Iteration: 1200 / 2000 [ 60%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 4: Iteration: 1400 / 2000 [ 70%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 4: Iteration: 1600 / 2000 [ 80%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 4: Iteration: 1800 / 2000 [ 90%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 4: Iteration: 2000 / 2000 [100%]  (Sampling)
#> Chain 4: 
#> Chain 4:  Elapsed Time: 1.488 seconds (Warm-up)
#> Chain 4:                1.66 seconds (Sampling)
#> Chain 4:                3.148 seconds (Total)
#> Chain 4:

mdl2$warnings
#> [[1]]
#> <simpleWarning: There were 20 transitions after warmup that exceeded the maximum treedepth. Increase max_treedepth above 10. See
#> https://mc-stan.org/misc/warnings.html#maximum-treedepth-exceeded>
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> <simpleWarning: Examine the pairs() plot to diagnose sampling problems
#> >

Created on 2024-04-17 with reprex v2.1.0
You can also print the warning with
conditionMessage(mdl2$warning)
[1] "Examine the pairs() plot to diagnose sampling problems\n"


This is a good start but unfortunately it only captures the last warning from the model fitting. Could this function be addapted so it stores every warning? If you run this model you'll have two warnings: brms::brm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width * Petal.Length * Petal.Width, data = iris, seed = 123)

@mat The first version, the one in the other answer, only captured the last warning. Then I adapted the code to return a list with all warnings, see if the code posted here solves your problem.
